# what is the set of points in the complex plane which satisfies |z| = Re(z) + 2?

Tags: complex-numbers

what is the set of points in the complex plane which satisfies |z| = Re(z) + 2?

so $ \sqrt{x^2+y^2} = x + 2 $ this is not a circle or anything and it asks me to sketch it what should I do

Answer (score 1):

Squaring it,
you get
$x^2+y^2 = x^2+4x+4$
or
$x =\dfrac{y^2}{4}-1$
which *is* a parabola,
but with the
usual axes switched.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\sqrt{x^2+y^2} = x = 2 \iff x^2+y^2 =(x+2)^2 \\
\iff x^2+y^2=x^2+4x+4 \\
\iff y^2=4x+4
$$